# "NOTE: REMINDSMA not using NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains" on IAP download

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, newsstand-kit

I have a Newsstand app that I'm updating for iOS8. When I download an in-app purchase, I'm now seeing a warning in the console I've never seen before that appears immediately before the IAP begins downloading:

> NOTE: REMINDSMA not using NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains

I'm using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` in the expected way throughout the app:

```
NSArray * docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * cacheDir = [docPaths objectAtIndex:0];
```

This warning doesn't seem to have any effect on the app's performance, but I'd like to address it. What is REMINDSMA? (It is totally ungoogle-able.) What service could be issuing this warning?

Comment: I'm currently asking myself the same... Did you find out what the message means?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't, but I'm glad that someone else is encountering this! However, it still seems to be a harmless warning and hasn't affected app performance.

Comment: me too :) Same - Seems benign